# Facing this error in android studio : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported`

Tags: java, android, kotlin, manifest

I am working on a source code I downloaded it from internet on android studio, but I am facing this errror whenever i build the project :

Error : Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#com.anchorfree.vpnsdk.vpnservice.AFVpnService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

I tried all the solutions possible available on internet, of which the solution deployed is that I add android:exported="true" to every `activity`, `service`, `receiver` and `provider` of merged `AndroidManifest`.

### **AndroidManifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />





    <application
        android:name="com.softmaster.airvpn.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:targetApi="n"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:node="merge">

        <activity
            android:name="com.softmaster.airvpn.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/splashTheme"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.softmaster.airvpn.activity.About"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"/>
        <activity android:name="com.softmaster.airvpn.activity.Faq"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"/> <!-- google ads -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.softmaster.airvpn.activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge"
            />


    </application>




</manifest>
```

### **BuildGradle File**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softmaster.airvpn"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_HOST", "\"https://d2isj403unfbyl.cloudfront.net\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_CARRIER_ID", "\"Sof_airvpn\""//54000_vpntest
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_OAUTH_METHOD", "\"anonymous\""

        buildConfigField "String", "SHARED_PREFS", "\"NORTHGHOST_SHAREDPREFS\""
        buildConfigField "String", "STORED_HOST_URL_KEY", "\"com.northghost.afvclient.STORED_HOST_KEY\""
        buildConfigField "String", "STORED_CARRIER_ID_KEY", "\"com.northghost.afvclient.CARRIER_ID_KEY\""

    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    namespace 'com.softmaster.airvpn'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:openvpn:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    //cutoms things
    //implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.6.0"


    //ad-mob and facebook mediation
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'//19.8.0
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.5.1.0'

    //customs
    implementation 'com.github.pepperonas:materialdialog:0.3.4'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'

    //Preference Library
    implementation 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.9.0'


    //Drawer Library
    implementation 'com.infideap.drawerbehavior:drawer-behavior:1.0.1'

    //checkBox
    implementation 'net.igenius:customcheckbox:1.3'


    //Custom Toast
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.0'

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.5.0"



}
```

I tried all the solutions possible available on internet, of which the solution deployed is that I add android:exported="true" to every activity, service, receiver and provider of merged AndroidManifest.

The error still keep coming.

Comment: Looking at the error it seems that one of the library 'openvpn' might be the one giving you this issue. you can upgrade this library, sync, rebuild and check if you still get any errors.

Comment: Thanks for ansewring! I am a little bit a begginer, can you tell me how to do that?